# Get a specific field as JsonArray from the JsonArray Object using GSON

Tags: json, gson

I have a JSON Structure as below

```
{
   "data" : [ {
          "x" : "1",
          "y" : "2",
          "z" : {"a":"8","b":"9","c":"10"}
        },
        {
          "x" : "3",
          "y" : "4",
          "z" : {"a":"6","b":"7","c":"11"}
        }
    ]
}
```

I can get the JsonArray as below,

```
JsonArray arrayData=jsonObj.getAsJsonArray("data");
```

However I need an JsonArray of a specific field(Say "z") as [{"a":"8","b":"9","c":"10"},{"a":"6","b":"7","c":"11"}]

Something like

```
JsonArray arrayZ=jsonObj.getAsJsonArray("data").getAsJsonArray("z");
```

How can this be acheived?

Comment: Check out the `get()` method for the JsonArray

Comment: get(int i) seems to return the ith element of the JsonArray

Answer (score 0):

You're jumping one step. 
   JsonArray arrayData=jsonObj.getAsJsonArray("data");
should return you an array with 2 positions, each position containg yet another array with 3 positions. 
After getting arrayData you should iterate through each position and in it get "z" again.